# FATAL DriverManagerPool newPooledObject Can't create a new connection for project SQL server in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, maven, tomcat8

2017-10-24 17:21:33.07] 0 FATAL DriverManagerPool newPooledObject Can't create a new connection for test on jdbc:sqlserver exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:
code: 0 state: 08001 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)    at com.cas.tff.server.connector.jdbc.DriverManagerPool.getDriverManagedConnection(DriverManagerPool.java:106)  at com.cas.tff.server.connector.jdbc.DriverManagerPool.createDBConnection(DriverManagerPool.java:66)   at com.cas.tff.server.connector.jdbc.DriverManagerPool.newPooledObject(DriverManagerPool.java:51)  at com.cas.tff.common.pool.Pool.allocateNewObject(Pool.java:1177)  at com.cas.tff.common.pool.Pool.initializePool(Pool.java:751)  at com.cas.tff.common.pool.Pool.initialize(Pool.java:739)  at com.cas.tff.server.connector.jdbc.JDBCPool.initialize(JDBCPool.java:179)    at com.cas.tff.common.pool.Pool.getInstance(Pool.java:561) at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolManager.createPool(PoolManager.java:106)    at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolManager.initializePools(PoolManager.java:243)   at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolManager.initialize(PoolManager.java:196)    at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolManager.(PoolManager.java:75) at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolManager.(PoolManager.java:68)   at com.cas.tff.common.pool.PoolingService.initialize(PoolingService.java:65)   at com.cas.tff.server.pool.ServerPoolingService.initialize(ServerPoolingService.java:40)   at com.cas.tff.common.registry.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:98)   at com.cas.tff.server.container.service.core.TUFServicesManager.initialize(TUFServicesManager.java:156)    at com.cas.tff.server.container.listener.ContextInitializerListener.contextInitialized(ContextInitializerListener.java:50) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[

Answer (score 0):

Add the given below maven dependency in your **pom.xml** file and run the **mvn clean install.**

```
**<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>**
```

if javax.transaction no class found error then add the below dependency

```
**<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>**
```